# расшифровка йцукен = qwerty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

есть говнокод который написал и он выводит данные приходящие в `json` вот он:

```
var timeout = null;
$('#searchword').bind('textchange', function (event, numberkey) {
    var keyword = $(this).val()
    //console.log("это1:" + keyword)    

    if(keyword.length > 3 && timeout == null)
            {
            $('#loader').show();
            timeout = setTimeout( function(){
                timeout = null;
                var keyword1 = $('#searchword').val();
                //console.log("это2:" + keyword1)
                var d = []
                $('#search_suggestion_holder li').detach();
                $('div.ui-tooltip').detach();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'auto-complete.php',
                    data:'keyword='+keyword1,
                    dataType:'json',
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('ошибка, F12');
                        console.log('jqXHR:');
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                        console.log('статус:');
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log('ошибка:');
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    },
                    success: function(d){
                    //console.log($.isEmptyObject(d));
                    if (!! $.isEmptyObject(d)){
                        //console.log("1")
                        var nafin = '<li class="hover-img">Ничего не найдено</li>'
                        $("#search_suggestion_holder").html(nafin)
                        $('#search_suggestion_holder').show();
                        $('#loader').hide();
                    }
                    else {
                    //console.log("2")

                    $.each(d, function(i, val) {
                        //console.log(val.icon + val.value);
                        //console.log(i);
                        var descrmin = val.descr.substr(0, 150);
                        //console.log(descrmin)
                        var hoverimg = "img-hover=\"<img src=/shop/medium/" + val.icon+"> <br> "+ descrmin + "\""
                        var resultat = '<li class="hover-img" title ' + hoverimg + '><img src="/shop/32x32/' + val.icon + '">' + val.value + '</li>'
                        //console.log(resultat)
                        $('#loader').hide();
                        $(resultat).appendTo("#search_suggestion_holder")
                        //console.log($("#search_suggestion_holder").html());
                        $('#search_suggestion_holder').show();
                        $(".hover-img").tooltip({
                            content: function (event, ui) {
                                    return $(this).attr('img-hover');
                                    },
                                    track: true,
                                });
                        })
                    }
                    }           
                });
            },700);
        }
    else if(keyword.length < 1){
            $('#search_suggestion_holder li').detach();
            $('div.ui-tooltip').detach();
            $('#search_suggestion_holder').hide();
            var newwrite = '<li class="hover-img">начните вводить</li>'
            //console.log(newwrite)
            $("#search_suggestion_holder").html(newwrite)
            $('#search_suggestion_holder').show();
            $('#loader').hide();
            }
    else if(1 > keyword.length < 3){

            $('#loader').show();
            $('#search_suggestion_holder li').detach();
            $('div.ui-tooltip').detach();
            $('#search_suggestion_holder').hide();
            var min3 = '<li class="hover-img">Введите больше 3 символов</li>'
            //console.log(min3)
            $("#search_suggestion_holder").html(min3)
            $('#search_suggestion_holder').show();
            $('#loader').hide();
            //console.log($("#search_suggestion_holder").html());
        }   
    })
```

как реализовать что бы при в воде `йцукен` он так же искал `qwerty` и на оборот, я полагаю нужно сделать массив `q = й` `w = ц` и так далее, если есть более простые решения, подскажите.

**UPDATE**

Написал такую функцию:

```
function Auto(str) {
        replacer = {
            "q":"й", "w":"ц"  , "e":"у" , "r":"к" , "t":"е", "y":"н", "u":"г", 
            "i":"ш", "o":"щ", "p":"з" , "[":"х" , "]":"ъ", "a":"ф", "s":"ы", 
            "d":"в" , "f":"а"  , "g":"п" , "h":"р" , "j":"о", "k":"л", "l":"д", 
            ";":"ж" , "'":"э"  , "z":"я", "x":"ч", "c":"с", "v":"м", "b":"и", 
            "n":"т" , "m":"ь"  , ",":"б" , ".":"ю" , "/":"."
        };       

        for(i=0; i < str.length; i++){                        
            if( replacer[ str[i].toLowerCase() ] != undefined){

                if(str[i] == str[i].toLowerCase()){
                    replace = replacer[ str[i].toLowerCase() ];    
                } else if(str[i] == str[i].toUpperCase()){
                    replace = replacer[ str[i].toLowerCase() ].toUpperCase();
                } 

                str = str.replace(str[i], replace);
            }
        }

       return str;
    }
```

Но такой вариант работает только в одну сторону `(q ---> й)`, как без использование дублирующего массива й:q сделать  что бы в обе стороны он мог работать `(q <---> й)(й <---> q)`

Comment: А почему именно qwerty -> йцукен? Есть же и другие раскладки, например "дворак". Но если вам надо именно так, то я не вижу другого варианта кроме ассоциированного массива для перекодировки.

Comment: вы видимо не совсем поняли, мне нужно что бы при вводе `hfwbz` он нашёл `рация`, а так же по поиску `пщзкщ` искал `gopro`

Comment: Ну так? Соотношение qwerty<->йцукен, это только один из вариантов. Есть и другие, как я уже привел пример, это дворак раскладка. Хотя если вам надо только самый популярный вариант, используйте только его.

Comment: @АлексейВасильев, а зачем, говорите, вы привели вот эту портянку кода?

Comment: хочу что бы через `js` шла обработка и подставлялась в `keyword1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На вскидку я бы сделал так, сделал бы два массива , один с английскими символами arr.ENG другой с русскими arr.RUS, дальше делаем к исходной строке .toLowerCase и разбиваем её на массив через .split , дальше тупо обходим нашу строку циклом, и если находим соответствие с arr.ENG то берём и заменяем на символ из массива arr.RUS , массивы должны совпадать индексами по буквам , то есть например arr.RUS[8] = "З" , а arr.ENG[8] = "Z". на выходе склеиваем из массива строку и всё готово, проверять исходный язык можно простым RegExp проверяя наличие хотя бы одной буквы из нужного алфавита в слове

Comment: Я посмотрел на свою клавиатуру и у меня "Z<->Я", а у вас почему-то "З", либо я не понял ваш ответ вообще. И легче создать два объекта с маппингом, как и предлагает автор вопроса.

Comment: а не в `php` а в `js` это можно сделать?

Comment: Vartlok , писал перед обедом, спешил и вписал для транслита, тут да, надо "З<->P" , Алексей Васильев  да я и писал применительно к JS, PHP бросил много лет назад ввиду его бесперспективности , но это не тема этого вопроса

Comment: @vnn198 Прошу у вас помощи скрестить вашу идею и мой код, это реально? или проще сделать отдельной функцией? Вообщем нужно хотя бы приблизительные наброски, дальше думаю что пойму принцип.

Comment: я бы в ф-цию завернул, код простой, просто объёмный

Comment: @vnn198 обновил первый пост, Сможете помочь?